# SQL Server, Error 102, when using CURSOR, creating a dynamic table

Tags: t-sql, dynamic, cursor, temp

I got the following error when using CURSOR in creating temp tables:

```
(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '?'.
Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 33
Invalid object name '##TEMP_Branch'.
```

without CURSOR everything works fine.
Here is the entire code:

```
declare  @TableSchema table
(
    Id  Int Identity(1,1),
    Name    nVarchar(50),
    DataType    nVarchar(50)
)

declare @reportid uniqueidentifier
set @reportid = '597d37c0-563b-42f0-99be-a15000dc7a65'
declare @ttl nvarchar(100)
declare cur CURSOR LOCAL for
    SELECT    title
    FROM            ReportItems
    where reportid = @reportid
    and del = 0 
    ORder by so
open cur
    fetch next from cur into @ttl
    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
        INsert @TableSchema Values(@ttl,'nVarchar(max) NULL')
    fetch next from cur into @ttl
    end
close cur
deallocate cur

Declare @Statement  Varchar(1000)
Select @Statement  = 'Create Table [##TEMP_Branch](FieldID Varchar(50)'
Select @Statement = COALESCE(@Statement +',','') + Name + ' ' + DataType from @TableSchema
Select @Statement = @Statement + ')'
EXEC(@Statement)


Select * from ##TEMP_Branch
drop table ##TEMP_Branch
```

Any kind help would be HIGHLY appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps, something's wrong with the dynamic query. Can you not `PRINT` it before or instead of executing it and take a look at what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

use a table varible

```
    Declare @TEMP_Branch TABLE
    (
       FieldID varchar(50)
    )
```

it work as regular table, without relation, and dont have to drop, for lager data process, make a permanent table to temporary store the data and after deleto or truncate it

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a title in the ReportItems table that has a blank space or other bad character (question mark) in it.

The first error looks like it coming out of the `EXEC(@Statement)` because the table definition is invalid.

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '?'.
```

The second error is probably `Select * from ##TEMP_Branch` being executed against a temp table that doesn't exist:

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 33
Invalid object name '##TEMP_Branch'.
```